# how do i do bulk insert or update statements in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i know there is a bulk insert in PHP that i can resolve easily in php

```
$list = array();
foreach($list as $key->$value){   $list[] = "($key, $value)";   }
$query = "insert into tblTest (a, b, c) values ".implode(",", $list);
$r = mysql_query($q);
```

and i know how to do a insert or update statement:

```
$insert into tblTest (a,b,c) values (1,2,3) on duplicate key update b=5;
```

I was not sure if this was the sufficient answer query i would want to run:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest (a, b, c) 
    VALUES(1, 2, 3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=VALUES(b), c=VALUES(c)
```

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: I was trying to figure out if the proper combining an insert or update and bulk insert was correct.  I never used `values(b)` before, but i figured that would be used to look at that particular insert, etc